# ConEmu + Ubuntu Bash: How to open new tab in current directory

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, conemu

I recently switched from GitBash to Ubuntu Bash.
I use the Ubuntu Bash with ConEmu.Unfortunately when I open a new tab the directory switches back to my user directory not the directory of the tab from where I opened a new tab.

Can anyone tell me how to configure ConEmu to open a new Ubuntu Bash in the directory of the last Ubuntu Bash tab?

<strike>It would be nice to know how to specify the default directory where ConEmu opens Ubuntu Bash aswell. I don't want it to be my user directory, but my workspace.</strike>

Solved by adding `-dir "myDirectory"` as parameters for my predefined task to open a bash.

With git bash I followed [maximus suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/942835/open-a-new-tab-in-conemu-in-the-same-directory-git-bash) and created a macro he provided

`Shell("new_console", "{Git bash}", "", "%CD%")`

and adding the following to my .bashrc

`PROMPT_COMMAND='ConEmuC -StoreCWD'`

And set up a call of Shell function in the Keys&Macros. Example assumes you have {Git bash} task.

As a first naive try I just created a new predefined task `{Bash:bash}` that simply executes `bash`which starts the ubuntu bash successfully.

Then I tried to change the macro to the following:

`Shell("new_console:n", "{Bash:bash}", "", "%CD%")`

Unfortunately the new console is still opened in the default directory.

Comment: Did you read docs? https://conemu.github.io/en/StartupDir.html

Comment: @Maximus Yes. I also read https://conemu.github.io/en/BashOnWindows.html but when trying to configure the task as the docs state I just get a notification that the path could not be found and the window closes immediately (had to reset the config in conemu.xml)

Comment: Just noticed that the latest "stable" build is 161206 and therefore the WSL bridge is not included.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `PROMPT_COMMAND='ConEmuC -StoreCWD'` I added the following from [the docs](https://conemu.github.io/en/ShellWorkDir.html#connector-ps1) to my `.bashrc`:

```sh
if [[ -n "${ConEmuPID}" ]]; then
  PS1="$PS1\[\e]9;9;\"\w\"\007\e]9;12\007\]"
fi
```

Then I created a new task in Startup > Tasks, which I cloned from the existing {Bash::bash} task and added `-cur_console:d:%CD%` as a startup parameter.